# display date in jqgrid with spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

I am using spring mvc with jquery grid. I have a date field in my row. in Json I get the date as

"releaseDate":1406399400000

**But it shows as "NaN/NaN/NaN" in the table**. In my bean class I keep it as java Date format. grid configuration column model is as follows.

```
colModel:[
               {name:'name', label: 'Product Name', width: 300},

               {name:'releaseDate', label: 'Release Date',formatter:'date',formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'}, width: 300}

           ],
```

I am using jqgrid 4.6. Any help is really appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example custom formatter which calls `formatter: "date"` with `srcformat: "u"` property in `formatoptions`. Try something like

```
{
    name: 'releaseDate',
    label: 'Release Date',
    formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'},
    formatter: function (value, options) {
        if (typeof value === "number" && value > 1000000000000) {
            return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", value/1000, options);
        } else {
            return "&nbsp;";
        }
    },
    width: 300
}
```

In case of string input value you can use `parseInt`. Probably you will have to provide [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) and `sorttype` as function too.